# Save PDF forms in legacy target version

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle-designer

**Version being used:**
Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES4 (Version: 11.0.0.20130303.1.892433)

LiveCycle Designer supports the ability to set a Target Version. This is so the rendered PDF file can be compatible with older versions of Adobe software (Or some other piece of software expecting a certain version).

The problem is, out-of-the box, this version of LiveCycle Designer only allows me set set a Target Version of 9.0 or later. I would like to set a Target Version of 7.0 or 8.0 in order to make my PDF files compatible with legacy software that only supports version 7 or 8 PDF files.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without having to use an older version of LiveCycle Designer?

Comment: Can you set a lower legacy version in Form Properties > Compatibility tab?

Comment: If I remember correctly, LCD ES4 is not able to create versions which can be understood by Acrobat 7 and 8. In any case, if you want/need to support Reader, there are incompatibilities. For supporting oder Acrobat/Reader versions, you may better stay with PDF forms (and avoid LCD).